# Hadoop is skipping reduce phase entirely

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have set up a Hadoop job like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Legion");
    job.setJarByClass(Legion.class);

    job.setMapperClass(CallQualityMap.class);
    job.setReducerClass(CallQualityReduce.class);

    // Explicitly configure map and reduce outputs, since they're different classes
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(CallSampleKey.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(CallSample.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    job.setInputFormatClass(CombineRepublicInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    CombineRepublicInputFormat.setMaxInputSplitSize(job, 128000000);
    CombineRepublicInputFormat.setInputDirRecursive(job, true);
    CombineRepublicInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));

    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
}
```

This job completes, but something strange happens. I get one output line per input line. Each output line consists of the output from a `CallSampleKey.toString()` method, then a tab, then something like `CallSample@17ab34d`.

This means that the reduce phase is never running and the `CallSampleKey` and `CallSample` are getting passed directly to the `TextOutputFormat`. But I don't understand why this would be the case. I've very clearly specified `job.setReducerClass(CallQualityReduce.class);`, so I have no idea why it would skip the reducer!

Edit: Here's the code for the reducer:

```
public static class CallQualityReduce extends Reducer<CallSampleKey, CallSample, NullWritable, Text> {

    public void reduce(CallSampleKey inKey, Iterator<CallSample> inValues, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Call call = new Call(inKey.getId().toString(), inKey.getUuid().toString());

        while (inValues.hasNext()) {
            call.addSample(inValues.next());
        }

        context.write(NullWritable.get(), new Text(call.getStats()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code of `CallQualityMap` and `CallQualityReduce` classes

Comment: Had figured it wasn't relevant, but I went ahead and added the code. Thanks.

Comment: Can you attach job.xml file for this run?

Comment: This was executed on AWS Elastic MapReduce. Any idea where I'd find the job.xml file? I can SSH to the master node if necessary.

Comment: Added controller and syslog output if that's any help.

Comment: No, they have `part`, as usual. I'll try out `setNumReduceTasks`, but I thought that was for specifying the number of reducers that will execute in the cluster?

Comment: Tried `setNumReduceTasks`. Same deal.

Comment: I suspect that your reducer code had issues. You are writing Null key. Can you change the order of parameters in Context.write? It's only a guess.

Comment: The fact that the reducer writes a null key is what tells me the reducer isn't running. The output is consistent with what would happen if the mapper output went directly to the output format, not if the reducer blew up.

Comment: According to your syslog reducer worked fine. It read 7682 input records and wrote 7682 output records. So the problem might be in your `Call.getStats()` method which generate your final output records. Can you attach the code of this method?

Comment: Is it possible it just used the identity reducer somehow? (I'll replace the reducer code with some dummy code that just outputs a `NullWritable` and a random string of text and see if that actually runs. I'll report back in a few.

Comment: Hokay. I removed all the code from `reduce()` and replaced it with only `context.write(NullWritable.get(), new Text("Blaaaaargh!"));`. Output didn't change. If the reducer was running, I would have gotten a bunch of lines of "Blaaaaaargh!" as output. The reducer is not running.

Comment: Open YARN history server (default address your_server_ip:19888/jobhistory) and check the number of finished mappers and reducers. It may help to make sure if the problem is that reducers have not been running. Futhermore there you can check the logs of any tasks.

Comment: The YARN history server shows that one reducer has completed. I'm convinced that SOME reducer is running, but it obviously isn't the reducer I've specified (as proved by the "Blaaaargh!" test mentioned above). Therefore, I have to imagine it's the identity reducer. I'm open to other theories, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you try to change your

```
public void reduce(CallSampleKey inKey, Iterator<CallSample> inValues, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
```

to use `Iterable` instead of `Iterator`?

```
public void reduce(CallSampleKey inKey, Iterable<CallSample> inValues, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
```

You'll have to then use `inValues.iterator()` to get the actual iterator.

If the method signature doesn't match then it's just falling through to the default [identity reducer implementation](https://github.com/apache/hadoop-mapreduce/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Reducer.java#L145). It's perhaps unfortunate that the underlying default implementation doesn't make it easy to detect this kind of typo, but the next best thing is to always use `@Override` in all methods you intend to override so that the compiler can help.

Comment: WOW! At home now, but I think you're correct. Will test in the morning. Can't believe it was such a stupidly simple oversight. I'll make sure you get your sweet, sweet internet points if this works out.

Comment: Yep, this was it. Thanks!